# Nginx gzip not working

Tags: nginx, gzip

I am having problems with gziping JS files using nginx. I have tired various different gzip configs out there but still no luck !

Current gzip config:

```
gzip on;
gzip_static on;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_min_length 100;
gzip_buffers 4 8k;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types text/plain application/javascript application/x-javascript text/javascript text/xml text/css;
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";
gzip_vary on;
```

A screenshot of the response [not gzipping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XFTt.png)

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: It's an obvious question, but I have to do it. Have you restarted the server? `sudo nginx -s reload`

Comment: Yeah, I've restarted it every time i made a change to the gzip config

Comment: Did you try gzip_http_version 1.0;